# How to show a message in phantom wallet while signing an anchor transaction?

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, phantom

I was wondering how is it possible to show a message while signing an anchor transaction since it creates a transaction by itself unlike how you do using @solana/web3.js. I just want to let user know why he/she is signing the transaction.

For eg:

```
const tx = await program.methods.initialize().accounts({
       baseAccount: programPDA,
       authority: user.publicKey
       }).rpc();
```

So the above the method would direcly open the mobile wallet and ask the user to sign. But along with this i want to show the message why the person has to sign. A message like this `Sign the transaction to initialize the PDA` while signing the tx is what i want.

Can anybody tell me how is this possible?

Comment: I suspect this isn't possible as it would provide a legitimate looking mechanism for scammers to trick users into signing malicious transactions.  Perhaps consider a different UX flow where the user is presented with your message _before_ the transaction is passed to the wallet.  Be sure to wait until _after_ the user proceeds to query a recent blockhash, otherwise a slow user's transactions may expire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Trent mentioned, it is not possible.

Best practice is let them know beforehand. There could be popup that says something like:

```
Looks like you haven't been using SuperApp before.
We are creating a SuperApp account for you.
This will involve a small fee payable in SOL and
approving a transaction in your wallet.

                       [ Got It ]
```

And then afterwards sending the `initialize` instruction.